# Crash when cast object inside for loop only on release mode

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I use method with for loop inside:

```
func filter (array: NSArray) -> NSMutableArray {
    var filteredArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for objects in array as [MyObject] { // this line crash only on release mode
        // TODO
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

when it is debug mode it works fine, but when I change to release mode it's crashed on line:

```
for objects in array as [MyObject]{
```

When I change method to this one (without casting inside loop) it wont crash on debug also on release mode:

```
func filter (array: [MyObject]) -> NSMutableArray {
    var filteredArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for objects in array {
        // TODO
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

Can some explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing what's actually inside the `NSArray`. I suggest setting a breakpoint and inspecting the content of the `array` variable.

However, the reason is that the `as` operator fails doing the cast, because at least one element in `array` is not an instance of (a subclass of) `MyObject`. I would protect that code by using optional cast, although that would skip the entire `for` loop if cast fails.

```
func filter (array: NSArray) -> NSMutableArray {
    var filteredArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    if let array = array as? [MyObject] {
        for objects in array as [MyObject] { // this line crash only on release mode
            // TODO
        }
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

If you are sure that the array contains `MyObject` instances, then I would solve the problem in the code that calls this function, using a swift array instead of `NSArray`, so avoiding cast problems, but of course that depends from your actual code - so this is not a solution that may work in all cases.

**Update** This solution could also better solve your problem, if it happens that you have an array with elements of mixed types, but you are interested in processing only the ones having `MyObject` type:

```
func filter (array: NSArray) -> NSMutableArray {
    var filteredArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for element in array {
        if let element = element as? MyObject {
            // TODO
        }
    }
    return filteredArray
}
```

The difference is that instead of trying to cast the entire array, the cast is attempted for each element.

Comment: Thanks! That first checking fixed my problem.

Comment: Good to know. However, even if it fixes the crash issue, there might be a bug somewhere else, because you are expecting an array containing elements of a certain type. Take a look at the updated answer.